# PHP remove numbers in brackets

Tags: php, regex

I have a string which looks like the following in PHP: `Foo [123][bar]` and I'd like to remove `[123]` from the string entirely so I end up with `Foo [bar]`.

Another example is `Blah [9484][M0200 blah blah blah]` which makes things more complicated because I can't simply remove all numbers and then remove empty brackets. The first set of brackets always contains a 3-4 digit number, and never any letters, however the second brackets can contain anything.

Any suggestions to how I'd go about doing this?
Thanks.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: Depends on what you'd like to have happen in the second situation, if you just want the [9484] removed, this seems like a very simple preg_replace. If however, you want the 0200 part removed as well then it gets more complicated.

Comment: I'm just after the first bracket being removed, so in the second example it'd become `Blah [M0200 blah blah blah]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex

```
\[\d{3,4}\]
```

will find all 3-4 digit numbers inside brackets.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/kH3nZ5/1

Used with preg_replace, http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php, this will replace all found instances.

```
echo preg_replace('~\[\d{3,4}\]~', '', 'Blah [9484][M0200 blah blah blah]');
```

Output:

> Blah [M0200 blah blah blah]

`\d` is any single number and `{3,4}` says at least 3 occurrences of a number and no more than 4.

Pages with more detailed info on regexs,
http://www.rexegg.com/
http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 0):

This is super simple with a preg_replace:

```
$str = "Foo [123][bar]";
$str = preg_replace("/\[[0-9]+\]/", null, $str);
```